# Best (Fastest) Arithmetic Algorithms

Tags: binary-arithmetic, arithmetic

What are the best arithmetic algorithms out there (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power, root)?

I am looking for algorithms that could be easily extended to multiprecision and arbitrary precision settings.

Comment: You are asking for the equivalent of a small textbook. Have you done some searching yourself? Can you focus the question more?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a "best" algorithm is not as simple as you'd expect. It depends on at least two more parameters: the machine model and the numbers involved (i.e., how large are the numbers being operated on). For a thorough discussion of this as regards integer multiplication, see Fürer's paper [How Fast Can We Multiply Large Integers on an Actual Computer?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1811)

There is a wikipedia page devoted to the [computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), including everything you mention. However, from a practical point of view, I would rather look at the source code of a strong library for multiprecision arithmetic like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Such a library is optimized for fastest performance on actual computers. The source code of GMP is readily available, and you can peek under the hood.